# Json generated with angular is messing up

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I want to generate json from a multi-array like this

```
var qus ={ 
{ 
"qus" :"what is your name?",
"option1" : {"ans" : Alex, "cor:"false"},
"option2" : {"ans" : Hervy, "cor:"false"},
"option3" : {"ans" : Rico, "cor:"true"},
"option4" : {"ans" : Tom, "cor:"false"},
},

{ 
"qus" :"what is your brother's name?",
"option1" : {"ans" : Alex, "cor:"false"},
"option2" : {"ans" : Hervy, "cor:"true"},
"option3" : {"ans" : Rico, "cor:"false"},
"option4" : {"ans" : Tom, "cor:"false"},
},

}
```

but it does not generate if I take the array value through a text area. (view this) 
http://plnkr.co/edit/hvuLXL1SPntlqtAV8iEW?p=preview 
It adds all the br tags.

And in here it is breaking up everything. (view this)
http://plnkr.co/edit/5qzsSSzv6oXV4QRpPa36?p=preview

Would you mind to explain? Why is it  not working if I take the value from a textarea? how do I get the result like the json I posted above from the messed up plnks?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do JSON.parse. You need to do it because "objects" object is an object of type "string". So when you do ***for-in***, you will be iterating over each character, which wont give the result you want. You have to parse the JSON string and get the array out of it. The rest of the logic seems fine.

Try this as your scope.generate function.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YW3jFTrTgdH4FfitfeMJ?p=preview

```
$scope.generate = function() {

  var objects = document.getElementById("inpt").value;

  var el = document.getElementById("out");

  var newObj = JSON.parse(objects);
  el.innerHTML += 'var qus ={ <br>';

  for (i in newObj) {
    var qset = newObj[i];

    el.innerHTML += '{ <br>';
    el.innerHTML += '"qus" :"' + qset[0] + '",<br>';

    for (n in qset) {
      if (n == 0) continue;
      var nameset = qset[n];

      el.innerHTML += '"option' + n;
      el.innerHTML += '" : {"ans" : ' + nameset[0];
      el.innerHTML += ', "cor:"' + nameset[1] + '"},<br>';
    }

    el.innerHTML += '},<br><br>';
  }
  el.innerHTML += '}';
  //el.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(objects);
  console.log(objects);

};
```

Comment: Plz solve this one and this one 

http://plnkr.co/edit/hvuLXL1SPntlqtAV8iEW?p=preview
and
 http://plnkr.co/edit/5qzsSSzv6oXV4QRpPa36?p=preview